# Get folder data through this web service IdcService="LIST_PATH" in ucm oracle gives csSystemCodeExecutionError

Tags: soapui, oracle-ucm

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ucm="http://www.oracle.com/UCM">
                        <soapenv:Header/>

                        <soapenv:Body>

                        <ucm:GenericRequest webKey="cs">

                            <ucm:Service IdcService="LIST_PATH">

                            <ucm:Document>
                                <ucm:Field name="IdcService">LIST_PATH</ucm:Field>
                                <ucm:Folder>
                                <ucm:Field name="path">Folders/Users/SCM02.STUDENT/demofolder</ucm:Field>
                                </ucm:Folder>
                            </ucm:Document>
                            </ucm:Service>
                        </ucm:GenericRequest>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

So this is the first time I'm doing this kind of task, so apologizes if something doesn't make sense at the beginning.
I am using this payload to get the data in folders present in ucm oracle But it gives this error csSystemCodeExecutionError

I am expecting the content inside the folder in UCM like the document id and data present inside these document IDs

Answer (score 0):

In a clean UCM installation, there is no service with the name `LIST_PATH`.
It might be that you have a custom service with that name, in which case you have some other problem.
Your first thing to try is to run `PING_SERVER`. If that works, you should be good to go.
Here is a list of all standard services:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/webcenter/content/12.2.1.4/services-reference/core-content-server-services.html#GUID-5443AA3F-DDE9-4E91-BB41-93651ABE7FFF